# Select distinct in two column but group by one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to select from the database results for make a menu as in example:

http://it.tinypic.com/r/2f092pv/8

Record sql example:

**Field**-------Product ----Macrocategories---Microcategories--Price----

**Value**-------Nvidia------ Hardware ----- Graphic Cards ---- 399$ -----

I tried this:

```
$select_MENU = "select distinct macrocategories, microcategories from catalog";

        $result_MENU = mysql_query($select_MENU);

if ($result_MENU)
        while($dati = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_MENU))
        {
        echo "<li><a>$dati[macrocategories]</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='index.php?microcategories=$dati[microcategories]'>$dati[microcategories]</a></li>
        </ul>";

        }
        ?>
        </ul>
```

The result: 1 `<li>`Macrocategories for each result of microcategories

Help me please...

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't have a double quote to close your `$select_MENU`?

Comment: I added a double quote in example code.

Comment: I am not sure if you want or don't want the `<ul>` in the loop. You have them inside and outside your loop.

Comment: How many rows do you expect?

Comment: Are you sure they are supposed to be distinct? If you make your `macrocategories` distinct it's only going to grab 1 instance of `Hardware`.

Comment: Rasclatt I want 1 instance of hardware and 1 istance of graphic card!!

Comment: Presumably all your subcategories have parent categories, so why not search for distinct subcategories and loop through those, create a new associative array where your subcategories are placed into their respective categories then loop through that array for display?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple oddities in your HTML in general:

```
// You will want to switch to PDO or mysqli prepared statements for security and deprecated reasons
// Distinct will only select unique instances in your table 
$select_MENU = "select distinct macrocategories, microcategories from catalog";
$result_MENU = mysql_query($select_MENU); ?>
<ul>
<?php
if($result_MENU) {
        while($dati = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_MENU)) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $dati['macrocategories']; ?></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?microcategories=<?php echo $dati['microcategories']; ?>"><?php echo $dati['microcategories']; ?></a></li><?php
            }
    } ?>
</ul>
```